# Is Ruby's Net::HTTP threadsafe on JRuby

Tags: ruby, multithreading, thread-safety, jruby

The `Net::HTTP` that ships with JRuby *appears* to be the same/similar to the one that ships with MRI Ruby.

Does anyone know if this implementation is, or is not, thread-safe (and, how you know).

My only evidence is the existence of the [net-http-persistent](https://github.com/drbrain/net-http-persistent/) library, which claims to be a thread-safe library that uses `Net::HTTP`.

Examining the source for `Net::HTTP` doesn't reveal any obvious shared state.

Anyone have any more info?

Comment: You should just ask @headius on Twitter. He's pretty fast answering JRuby questions.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you mean by thread safe. Net::HTTP uses TimeOut which is generally considered broken because of it's use of Thread#raise and thread#kill.
Look here...
http://blog.headius.com/2008/02/rubys-threadraise-threadkill-timeoutrb.html

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak for Net::HTTP, but not all of JRuby's code is thread-safe. For example, [Data safety and GIL removal](http://merbist.com/2011/10/18/data-safety-and-gil-removal/) shows that Array isn't thread safe. This is also stated on the [JRuby wiki](http://kenai.com/projects/jruby/pages/RailsMulti-ThreadingBestPractices).